# HTML Submit Button positioning issue in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, submit, form-submit

which is almost right on Chrome and firefox but the problem is the position of the submit button on IE if too right than the css. Please check the code and help as soon as possible.

HTML &CSS Code you can find on the link http://jsfiddle.net/7vUW6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i saw your codings and fix the issues , you had some mistakes  accroding to the input box not set the proper width.
Then the submit button is also i fix the issues and i check all the browers now alignment is correct.The edit coding as follows. please copy this code and run your system.

### complete codings:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Customer Advance and Project Registration System | Ymoff Technologies Pvt. Ltd.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is Project Registration and Customer Advance Payment Recept System designed and developed for Ymoff Technologies." />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").validate();
      });
      </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clearThis(target){
            target.value= "";
        }
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function autoGrow (oField) {
      if (oField.scrollHeight > oField.clientHeight) {
        oField.style.height = oField.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    /*-- Reset CSS --*/
    .wraper{
            width:70%;
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding:0;
        }

        #field {

        }
        #ftext{
            font-family: 'Capriola', sans-serif;
        }
        #btext{
            font-family: 'Quando', serif;
            font-weight:400;
        }
        #space{
            padding-left:5%;
        }
        .submit{
            padding-left:54%;
            padding-right:60%;
            clear:both;
        }
        #value{
            color:#999;
        }
        textarea {
      resize: none;
    }
    #noscrollbars {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #inform{
        color:#C00;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align:justify;
    }
    select{
        color:#00F;
    }
    textarea{
        border-right: #a9a9a9 1px solid;
      border-top: #a9a9a9 1px solid;
      border-left: #a9a9a9 1px solid;
      border-bottom: #a9a9a9 1px solid;
      color:#00F;
    }
    #show1{
        color:#10e684;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:600;
    }
    #show2{
        color:#9e2a28;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:600;
    }
    #show3{
        color:#9e2a28;
        font-size:10px;
    }
    fieldset{
        width:400px;
        padding-top:5px;
    }
    legend{
        font-family: "Quando", serif;
    }

    .umame
    {

        text-align:right;
        float:left;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        padding-right:8px;
    }
    .umame1
    {

        text-align:left;
        float:left;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body class="wraper">
    <div>
        <img src="images/dashboardlogin.png" style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:15%;"  />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="container">
        <center>
        <br  /><br  /><br  />
        <h2 id="btext">Please perfectly enter the following fields :</h2>
           <form name="login" action="" method="post">
           <fieldset>
           <table width="337" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
           <tr>
               <td width="169" class="umame">
               <span id="ftext">Client Registration ID <span style="color:#C00;">*</span></span>
               </td>
                   <td width="156" class="umame1">
                   <input type="text" name="userid" value="Cleint Registraion ID" style="color:#999; width:156px;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value='';}this.style.color='#000';" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue;this.style.color='#999';}" />
                   </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="umame" width="169">
               <span id="ftext">Temporary Password <span style="color:#C00;">*</span></span>
               </td>
                    <td width="156" class="umame1">
                   <input type="password" name="password" value="***************" style="color:#999; width:156px;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value='';}this.style.color='#000';" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue;this.style.color='#999';}" />
                   </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="umame" width="169"> &nbsp;</td>
               <td width="156" class="umame1">
               <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Login" />
               </td>
           </tr>
           </table>
           </fieldset>
           </form>
           <table width="337">
           <tr>
                   <td ><span id="inform"><br />
                     * Marks fields are sent to you by E-Mail when your project has been registered with us. If any how if you lost our mail and want to get your Password, please visit this link <a href="#">Get Password</a> with your YMOFF Registration ID. </span>
                   </td>
           </tr>
           </table>

          </center>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center it, remove class="submit" and replace it with style="text-align: center;".
That will center the button in the row.

Also for IE, don't forget to specify a DOCTYPE declaration in your markup. Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Comment: It is already has been mentioned. I used a normal padding css for submit class.